# how to make a facebook app request a specific id for each user?

Tags: facebook, variables

This is the first time I am using FB's API and I was wondering how would you make an app request a specific id for each individual user? Basically what I am doing is setting up a page hosting service and I would need to have the app request the specific page for each user apart. This might be trivial but I couldn't find any info on this! Any info is greatly appreciated!

Thank you,
Anton

Comment: you cant generate app request id, its generated by facebook.  And using that app request id, you can get the info of the user.

Comment: Thanks Aby, this seems to be the way to go. I was going the wrong way, trying to set a unique identifier on my side then use that in the fb app for the page request.

Comment: please check the answer below, i have attached couple of links which might be useful

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using :

FQL : http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/apprequest/
or
By graph api : http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/464/